# WP-login redirecting to the complete wrong area

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hi I've created a dev site for testing my creations before they go live.
I've come to the site and all the images aren't there so I thought that may be a problem with the uploads folder, reuploaded from the live site and they still didn't appear.

Came to log in to wp-login and there was no styling on the login fields. Was strange so I tried to log in and it sent me to dev.mysite.com/dev.mysite.com/wp-login.php

So as you can see it seems to like to send me to a duplicate of the url and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

My wp-config file is as is:

```
define('WP_HOME','dev.mysite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','dev.mysite.com');
```

I've change my actual url for security reasons as I work for a healthcare company. I'm sure you guys can understand. Any Idea why I might be getting redirected?

Also when I type in dev.mysite.com/wp-admin it takes me to the backend of wordpress as I have logged in through the buggy no styled form but then the backend of wordpress has no styling what so ever. See image below:

[None Styled Wordpress Backend Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPVvc.png)

Really hope someone is able to help as I'm baffled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL should be a full URI, ie. `http://dev.mysite.com`. Also make sure your htaccess don't contain any wrong path redirects.

Edit: You get un-styled admin because Wordpress has the wrong base URI, so it is searching for stylesheet and scripts in the wrong folders. If you open the developer console you will prolly see a lot of 404 errors (file not found).

Comment: *Facepalm* I changed that and it has worked. I can't believe that was the answer. I recently changed that to what is in the question and some reason really don't know why.

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Feel free to mark my answer as resolved so others with this problem can easier find it.